# How should I store a shared object in Spring MVC to use in multiple JSP's?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am creating a shopping cart application to learn Spring MVC. I want to display list of all categories and subcategories in more than one page. i.e; Home Page, Products page, Category page.

In the Home Page controller I am retrieving the list of categories,subcategories and featured products and passing them to the home page.

```
@Controller
public class CatalogController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryConfigService categoryConfigurationService;
    @Autowired
    private ProductConfigService productConfigurationService;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(CatalogController.class);

    /**
     * Catalog Controller method which retrieves the information required in the
     * application home page(Categories,SubCategories)
     * 
     * @return Home Page View
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String returnHomePage(Model model) {
        logger.info("Processing information for home page");
        List<Category> categoriesList = categoryConfigurationService
                .getAllCategories();
        Map<Category, List<SubCategory>> categoryMap = new HashMap<Category, List<SubCategory>>();
        for (Category category : categoriesList) {
            List<SubCategory> subCategoryList = categoryConfigurationService
                    .getAllSubCategoriesByCategoryId(category.getId());
            categoryMap.put(category, subCategoryList);
        }
        model.addAttribute("categoryMap", categoryMap);
        model.addAttribute("featProd",
                productConfigurationService.getFeaturedProducts());

        return "home";
    }


}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I store the object `categoryMap` in Spring to access it in multiple pages??
2. I have done the same project using JSP and Servlets and I have stored the `categoryMap` in application scope so that I can use it in multiple pages. Is this a right approach ? If not how can I do this in a better way ?

Please help!! Thanks

Edit: I want to display this category and subcategories list in the header of my application so that I can use these in all the pages.(like below image)

[image]

Edit: Is there any other approach to follow other than writing the code for fetching the categories  list from database in every controller ?

Answer (score 1):

If this list is different for each user , then keep in session scope. Else if it is common across the application , you can have singleton scope.

Best amoung all the solutioins availabe , you can use below steps :-

1.For acessing the list throughout the application , keep it in your singleton service class, as class variable and acess in controller by autowiring your service.

2. For displaying it in header, you need to add it in model, either you have to add it in model again and again from each controller method. Or you can add it as session attribue in model by using annotatoin @sessionattribute.

Yes, for perfect design, there should be some way , to add the attribute as application level. however, spring goes not have such support.

Comment: Yes, the list is same for all users, but can we really store data in singleton scope ? Can you please elaborate your answer with a code example ?

Comment: You would make a service out of your category which you inject. That service should now be a singleton that is shared across the application. That's the simplest thing you can do. `@Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService; ` and in your mapping you would get the map from the service: `model.addAttribute("categoryMap", categoryService.getYourMap());` Don't bring your other logic into the controller, do it in service.

Comment: Yes, you can keep map in your service and use it, however as multiple threads will be updating it from each controller , you need to make its updation tread-safe using synchronization

Comment: @Vaelyr So I should access this `model.addAttribute("categoryMap", categoryService.getYourMap());` in every controller(Ex: HomePageController,ProductPageController and CategoryPageController) ?

Comment: Ok, I thought about that but what if I want to use my data in a header ? Like this site [flipkart.com](http://www.flipkart.com/). Then I would just dynamically include the header.jsp right ? My actual thought process is to display the list of categories and subcategories in the header so that I can display it in all my pages.

Comment: you can use  @SessionAttributes("categoryMap") in this case

Comment: hmm.. but as per my knowledge, if the user is inactive for more than 30 mins the session data will be lost right ? So is it a good idea to store this data in session? Correct me if I am wrong!!

Comment: updated the answer, so that everything will be at one place. @SaiUpadhyayula you need to follow both to get best out of this problem

Comment: @Panther Thanks!! I will wait for some more answers!! +1 :)

Comment: Sure, i will also try to find more on this. You have raised really good question. And i am curious to know better solution

Comment: What's stopping you just using it as a service, why is the session important for you?

Comment: @Vaelyr I am just hoping for any other solution than using it as a service in every controller in my application. :)

Comment: If you don't want to do it in every controller, then use Controller Advice which intercepts all your request mapping calls and adds that map as model attribute.

Comment: @Vaelyr I missed your comment. Yes that was indeed the only meaningful way to use ControllerAdvice Annotation instead of manually adding the Map in every Controller as Model Attribute. Please post this as the answer :)